# Graceful shutdown of Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with 4 brokers, managed by 5 zookeepers.

The IPs of 5 zookeepers are going to be changed simultaneously, so I need to **stop all kafka nodes** before it and then (after the zookeepers IPs change) start them again.

From Kafka documentation I know, that I can add the parameter:

```
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
```

And then send this command to kafka broker:

```
bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
```

But it is relevant to one node restart (rolling restart).

1. Can I make the full restart more graceful, then just by stopping all kafka
   services at one time? I want kafka to recover as fast as possible
   after the full restart. Maybe I can send kafka a signal, that the
   whole cluster is going to be shut down?
2. Is there any risk of data loss if I stop and start kafka like that? (Zookeepers are just changing their IPs at once, the data on Zookeepers is not changed).

**Kafka version**: 2.4.0

**Zookeeper version**: 3.4.13

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop a cluster gracefully, first stop producing new events to it and stop all consumers. this will ensure you will have no data losses during complete shutdown.

Once the cluster is idle you can stop each node until the last one is stopped.
Then change your ZK IP addresses -> Update Kafka config to work with the new ZK IP addresses and start the Kafka cluster, you can do it one by one or at once.

`controlled.shutdown.enable` ensures that during node shutdown the data won't get loss and the data will be written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I stop kafka nodes, do I need to do it one by one - or just all nodes at once?

Comment: You can do it one by one, in each Kafka cluster, one of the nodes acts as the cluster Controller. you can identify who is the current controller by querying ZK GET /<Kafka Namespace>/controller.
This controller responsible to handle replication and leadership of each partition, so when a node is shutdown the Controller is responsible to update the partition state.
If you shutdown the controller, a new controller will be elected immediately.

You better stop the cluster one by one